# high charts - lost animation when pie chart sliced is programmatically set

Tags: javascript, highcharts

As you can see from this basic example, http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic
when you select a pie, the selected pie got pulled out slowly with animation.
and that is handled by this option.

```
pie: {
     allowPointSelect: true
}
```

However, I don't want mouse click to select Point. I have, say, a button outside of the pie chart, when I press the button, the first pie/Point should be selected.

I have the following

```
$scope.SAWChartConfig.series[0].data[0].selected = true;
$scope.SAWChartConfig.series[0].data[0].sliced = true;
```

programatically set the first point as selected when button clicked. It works fine, but it lost the animation (where it should slowly pull outward).

My questions are:

1. how can i add the animation back?
2. series[0].data contains a few data points, I would need to reset data[i].sliced to false for each of them after button is clicked. Is there a easy way to do it instead of loop through all items?

> .controller('spendingPieChartCtrl', ['$scope', '$q',
>   'TransactionService', 'CategoryService','chartColors', function
>   ($scope, $q, TransactionSvc, CategorySvc, chartColors) {
>       if(typeof $scope.height === 'undefined') {
>           $scope.height = 140;
>       }
>       $scope.SAWChartConfig = {
>           options: {
>               chart: {
>                   plotBackgroundColor: null,
>                   plotBorderWidth: null,
>                   plotShadow: false,
>                   type: 'pie',
>                   margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
>                   spacingTop: 0,
>                   spacingBottom: 0,
>                   spacingLeft: 0,
>                   spacingRight: 0,
>                   height: $scope.height
>               },
>               plotOptions: {
>                   pie: {
>                       dataLabels: {
>                           enabled: false
>                       },
>                       size: '100%',
>                       borderWidth: 0
>                   },
>                   series: {
>                       states: {
>                           hover: {
>                               enabled: false
>                           }
>                       }
>                   }
>               },
>               title:{
>                   text: null
>               },
>               tooltip: {
>                 enabled: false
>             }
>           },
>           series: [{
>               data: []
>           }]
>       };
>
> ```
> $q.all([
>     TransactionSvc.get(),
>     CategorySvc.get()
> ]).then(function() {
>     var spendingCategories = TransactionSvc.getTopCategories();
>     //redraw the chart by updating series data
>     $scope.SAWChartConfig.series = [{data: spendingCategories}];
> });
>
> $scope.$on('talkToOne', function( event, data ){
>     $scope.SAWChartConfig.series[0].data[index].select();
>     //$scope.SAWChartConfig.series[0].data[index].sliced = true;
> });
> ```

I am using ng-hightcharts, and here is the directive call

> 

Comment: Can you share your code in a fiddle

Comment: I guess that you use a highcharts-ng, that is correct?

Comment: @SebastianBochan, yes i am using angular-ng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chart.series[0].data[index].select()` will do the select/deselect of the slices without loosing animation.

See the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xpLpwpsx/1/)

By using above code your second problem will also get fixed, since the next select call will automatically deselect other selected slices in the chart.

Comment: Hi Navas, thanks for you replies. sorry i should be more specific. i am using highchart-ng and angular, i tried  $scope.SAWChartConfig.series[0].data[index].select() but i am getting the following error. TypeError: $scope.SAWChartConfig.series[0].data[index].select is not a function

Comment: my code is not short, i guess i have come up with a simple example and post it in fiddle in order to get better help then?

Comment: i have added my simple code into my question. thanks

Comment: @innek Oh !! Didn't got enough clue from your question, Alright. I dont have hand sown knowledge about ng-highchart, Thanks for the introduction, Will definitely look into it. Hope someone will figure out the solution for your question!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! problem solved. thanks to your big hint. i ended up doing this     $scope.$on('talkToOne', function( event, data ){
        var chart=Highcharts.charts[0];
        chart.series[0].data[index].select();
    });